# Quiz gives wrong answer even though I answered correctly PYTHON

Tags: python

I'm quite the noobie when it comes to  python programming. However I need as soon as possible a quiz making program which gives me % score at the end. Here's what I've done so far:

```
#coding: utf-8

from random import shuffle

qas = [
('Kvarts', 'SiO2'),
('Gull', 'Au'),
('Sølv', 'Ag'),
('Kobber', 'Cu'),
('Platina', 'Pt'),
('Grafitt', 'C'),
('Diamant', 'C'),
]

shuffle(qas)
numRight = 0

for question, rightAnswer in qas:
answer = raw_input(question + ' ')
if answer.lower( ) == rightAnswer:
print 'Correct'
numRight +=1
else:
print 'Wrong, the correct answer is ' + rightAnswer
print 'You got %d and %d wrong.' % (numRight, len(qas) - numRight)
```

I get the program to work slightly but even though I answer correctly it still gives me wrong answer like this:

```
Diamant C
Wrong, the correct answer is C
Kvarts SiO2
Wrong, the correct answer is SiO2
```

I don't know what to do to fix this.

Comment: Please edit your post so it has proper indentation, for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to call `answer.lower()` as this returns a string with *lowercase letters* while the correct answer may contain uppercase ones.

You can do `answer.strip()` instead. This removes white spaces at the beginning and end of input string.

Another option is to simply do `answer == rightAnswer`, but this will result in `'Wrong answer'` if `answer` is surrounded by white spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The answers in your list are not lowercase. If user inputs `C` your condition will evaluate `'C'.lower() == 'C'` (Just an example). Try

```
if answer.lower() == rightAnswer.lower():
```

Answer (score 0):

You check if the answer is correct by using

```
if answer.lower( ) == rightAnswer:
```

This converts the `answer` to lowercase (e.g. `C` to `c`)

The answers in the dictionary are case sensitive:

```
"C" == "c" => False
```

You have 3 options:

1 Convert the answers in the dictionary to uppercase:

```
qas = [
('Kvarts', 'SIO2'),
('Gull', 'AU'),
('Sølv', 'AG'),
('Kobber', 'CU'),
('Platina', 'PT'),
('Grafitt', 'C'),
('Diamant', 'C'),
]
```

Or 2: (the opposite) change everything to lowercase

Or 3: do not call `.lower`